# Subclass of Django Model Not Accessible from Superclass

Tags: python, django, inheritance, model

I'm trying to create an inherited model in Django like that below. I should be able to call, for an instance superclass = Superclass(), I should be able to call superclass.subclass, and access the requisite fields. When I do that, I'm told that '1 argument was expected, and 8 were given': any idea where I'm going wrong?

```py
class Superclass(models.Model):
        pass

class Subclass(Superclass):
        def __init__(self):
                super(Subclass, self).__init__()
```

Comment: Your super call also won't work because you can only use the class as the first argument to super. Ie. `super(Subclass, self)` not `super(Group, self)`

Comment: Yes – that was a mistake in the question, but isn't the problem.

Comment: Plus, you won't be able to do `superclass.subclass` anyway - inheritance is an "is-a" relationship, not a "has-a".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you need `*args` and `**kwargs` in the subclass constructor and superclass constructor. These two fields will take in the arguments and objects: these include the field information for the superclass, as well as the object manager, among other things. This should do the trick:

```py
class Subclass(Superclass):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(Subclass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```